# Sequence $\frac{(-2)^{n!}}{n^n}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that the sequence

$$\frac{(-2)^{n!}}{n^n}$$

diverges.

My only idea was to use that $n^n \geq n!$ , but it didnt help much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\frac{(-2)^{n!}}{n^n}=\left(-\frac{2^{(n-1)!}}n\right)^n$$

Comment: @Giiovanna there's a \leq that should be \geq

Comment: Note that since $n!$ is almost always even, the minus sign is just a potential distraction.

Answer (score 6):

$\left|\dfrac{(-2)^{n!}}{n^n}\right| = \dfrac{2^{n!}}{n^n} = (\dfrac{2^{(n-1)!}}{n})^n$.

Remark that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{2^{(n-1)!}}{n} = +\infty$

Comment: Does the divergence of the modulus of the sequence guarantee the divergence of the sequence?

Comment: @Giiovanna yes, if a series is convergent, then its n-th term converges to 0

Comment: Serie? I didint understand, can you explain? I could prove the divergence of the modulus, but not of the sequence itself.

Comment: @Giiovanna just a synonym for sequence

Comment: @Giiovanna: If a sequence $a_n$ converges to a limit $L$ then the inequality $||a_n| - |L|| \leq |a_n - L|$ implies that $|a_n|$ converges to $|L|$, so if the modulus does not converge, then neither does the sequence.

Comment: @Giiovanna: Note also that $n!$ is an even number for $n \geq 2$, so $(-1)^{n!} = 1$ for $n \geq 2$. So the sequence and its modulus coincide for $n \geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n \geq 3$ we have

$$\left| \frac{(-2)^{n!}}{n^n} \right| =\left(\frac{2^{(n-1)!}}{n} \right)^n  $$

Now, by Bernoulli inequality
$$\frac{2^{(n-1)!}}{n}=\frac{(1+1)^{(n-1)!}}{n}\geq \frac{1+1\cdot(n-1)!}{n}\geq 
\frac{(n-1)!}{n} \geq \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{n}\geq n-3$$